# Is there any way to get current time and minutes from SQL to compare with date time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to compare a `datetime` column with current time up to the minutes. However, I can only compare it up to days as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM ScheduleTable
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  = YEAR(schedule)
AND   MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = MONTH(schedule)
AND   DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)   = DAY(schedule)
```

So, is it possible to compare the hours and minutes too?

Comment: What is the database and version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hours and minutes, there's just no "shortcut" function you can use - you need to resort to using `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ScheduleTable 
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = YEAR(schedule) 
  AND MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = MONTH(schedule) 
  AND DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = DAY(schedule)
  AND DATEPART(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = DATEPART(HOUR, schedule)
  AND DATEPART(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = DATEPART(MINUTE, schedule)
```

See the [official MS docs entry for `DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `schedule` column is a datetime whose second and millisecond portion is always zero, you could simply zero out the seconds and milliseconds of current timestamp for comparison:

```
WHERE schedule = DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

If second and millisecond portion of `schedule` column could be non-zero then use this logic instead:

```
WHERE schedule >= DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
AND   schedule <  DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1, 0)
```

The expression produces [this result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c09566f7eba98d67fb62ad457ca9cd2).

Comment: +1 as the first option is index friendly. To get an index friendly version of the second version one could alter the first version to give the current time accurate to the minute and additionally the next minute of the current time and do a range comparison.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
SELECT * FROM ScheduleTable WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,schedule) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AND 
    DATEPART(MONTH,schedule) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AND 
    DATEPART(DAY,schedule) = DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())
```

Comment: That's not adding any new checks/features to the original posting .... you're just using `DATEPART` instead of the "shortcut" methods......

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `NOW()`. It returns the value of current date and time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format depending on the context (numeric or string) of the function.

To get specific part of the date you can use [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Syntax: `DATEPART(interval, date)`